# Conditional Formatting with increasing colors

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2013, conditional-formatting

I have a list of repeating table names:

```
Table1
Table1
...
Table2
...
Table99
```

I was wondering if there was anyway to use Excel conditional formatting to highlight each different table name a different color using some sort of increment.

So table1 would be 000033 and table2 000066 and so on using the hex value

I can write the conditional to say if R <> R-1 then new color or if R=R-1 then same color, but it is the color part that has me stumped.

I can write a VB function if needed but I was looking for a quicker solution.

Comment: The color is not the only problem. There is another one: conditional formatting in Excel 2013 only supports up to 5 colors (natively). If you use the formulas then you could push it up to 8 colors. But looking at your sample data it seems to me that you are looking for many more colors (will be a very colorful sheet). But in the end you are right: all formatting is "hard coded" into the formatting condition and is not dynamic. The only possibility is to use a `2-Color Scale` or `3-Color Scale`. In such cases the color is dynamically assigned. But you couldn't give it a particular hex-value.

Comment: Maybe I can use a rotating 3 colors, so if <> and color is green then red... something like that but how can I get the backcolor

Comment: That's for you to decide. Only you know the requirements. :)

Comment: @pnuts I was talking about the possible colors per conditinal formatting rule. Of course, if you stack a couple hundred rules one over the other then there are many more possibilities. But then you're running into the next problem of managing / tracking all of these rules and color coding schemas (which one goes first and after which to stop etc...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might cycle through three colours (provided the numbers for your Tables are sorted in numerical order) with CF formula rules such as:

```
=MOD(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"Table",""),3)=1
```

and `=1` replaced by `=2` and `=0` for the other colours.

If you really want more colours (say `10`) change the `3` to `10` and add rules for `=3` etc. All 99 should be possible (though IMO not necessary).